# Perform addition of values from each cell of tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on a Shopping app where I add items in cart. Now I have to show the sub total amount where I need to perform addition of price of each item in table.

How can I pick values from each cell and add them?

Below is the code for tableview:

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return  [CartList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *cellData = [[[CartList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"AddtoCartProductImageModel"] firstObject];
    NSString *image=[cellData valueForKey:@"productimg"];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://dealnxt.com/areas/user/productimage/%@", image];
    NSURL *Url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:Url];

    NSString *CellData = [[CartList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"shortdescription"];

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CartTableViewCell *cell = (CartTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];
    cell.proimg.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.prlbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.prlbl.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.prlbl.text=CellData;
    cell.prprice.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"₹%@",[[CartList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"price"]];
    cell.quantity.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[CartList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"quantity"]];


  NSString *string =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[[CartList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"price"]];
  int value = [string intValue];

  for (int i=0; i<=[CartList count]; i++) {

    int Total=0;
    Total=+value;
    NSLog(@"total:%d",Total);
}

    return cell;
}
```

Where prprice is what I need to add.

Comment: Don't pick values from cells, pick them from whatever place that stores the values that you display.

Comment: dont base on the UI. add the amount based on the data you have, the items you pass to an array i supposed to create the list of cart items

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  okay , so i need to create a for loop and it will run till the no. of rows and perform addition of value within the loop ? is that ?

Comment: @Shikha There's lots of approaches that you can follow - for example, total up the prices as items get added to the cart, and treat it as an additional row in UITableView.

Comment: Sheikhs, you're the one writing your app. We don't know what it's supposed to do, or what your data represents. If your table view represents a bunch of items who's prices you are supposed to sum then yes, you should sum the prices, and a for loop would be a way to do that.

Comment: @DuncanC i have added code above. please check out, if you can help me.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight please check the above code and help me.

Comment: float tot;
for (int i = 0; i < [CartList count]; i++)
{
    
tot = tot +  [[[CartList objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"price"] floatValue];
    // Do stuff...
}
NSLog("Total Cost : ₹ %.2f",tot);

Comment: @JigneshB i tried it as well but didn't worked, if there are 4 rows, the this loop is executed 16 times

Comment: So post the code you tried that didn't work.

Comment: @DuncanC I did.

Comment: The for loop code you posted makes no sense.  You create a local variable `Total` (should be `total) inside the loop, and set it to 0 each time through the loop. You need define your total variable and set it to zero outside the loop. Also you add `value` on each pass, which you **don't** set to the value of the current entry in your CartList array entry.

Comment: The code you posted tells me that you don't understand the very basics of programming, and are in way over your head. You need to go back and study the fundamentals or you aren't going to get anywhere.

Comment: @DuncanC thank you for your opinion , you are no one to tell me what to do. thanks again for your time

Comment: I can offer you advice, and its your prerogative to ignore it.

Comment: @DuncanC it's not an advice , you are demotivating me.

Comment: To the contrary, I'm trying to prevent you from trying to do more than you are ready for and get discouraged. You need to learn some basics like scope and the difference between local, instance, and global variables.

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks A lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //  write this code somewhere where you fill the CartList variable value.

float tot;
for (int i = 0; i < [CartList count]; i++)
{

tot = tot +  [[[CartList objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"price"] floatValue];
    // Do stuff...
}
NSLog("Total Cost : ₹ %.2f",tot);
```

Comment: It worked :) ThankYou , please vote up my question such that further people will get help.

Comment: Actually your question is quite bad. Unclear and incomplete.

Comment: @DuncanC it may be but it will help others.

Comment: @FahimParkar okay :)

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what the class of the objects in your CartList array, but the code might look something like this:

```
double total = 0;
for (anItem in CartList) {
  total += (double) anItem["price"];
}
```